# a.out permission issue during gcc build

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am building gcc 4.8.4 manually on a 64bit system which already has a gcc 4.6.3.
The problem is in the build phase. and seems to be that `a.out` isn't  an executable file.

```
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
checking for --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs... no
checking for --enable-generated-files-in-srcdir... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... /root/gcc/mega/./gcc/xgcc -B/root/gcc/mega/./gcc/ -B/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include   
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: in `/root/gcc/mega/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgomp':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgomp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc/mega'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc/mega'
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

Here is more information about the build itself.

```
    ../gcc-4.8.4/configure --prefix=/usr \
                           --mandir=/usr/man \
                           --libexecdir=/usr/lib \
                           --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,go \
                           --enable-threads=posix \
                           --enable-__cxa_atexit \
                           --enable-clocale=gnu \
                           --enable-shared --disable-nls \
                           --with-x=no --with-system-zlib \
                           --without-cloog --without-ppl --disable-multilib
```

this phase went with no problem. `make BOOT_CFLAGS='-O2 -march=native -pipe' bootstrap` ends with the problem I mentioned above.

here is the *config.log* file inside libgomp directory:
[libgomp log](http://codepad.org/Obx9QdOj)

and here is the *config.log* inside the gcc itself:
[gcc log](http://codepad.org/Ii2HaOsL)

Comment: Is it actually a permission issue? Are you building on a filesystem mounted noexec or something like that?  Or is the binary produced not one compatuble with your operating system / dynamic linker?

Comment: IIRC recent kernels only support elf executables in the default config.  You or your distro would have to enable a.out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am building on a ext4 partition mounted like `mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/X`. I am doing all of my work on a root user I might add.

Comment: @technosaurus as I am doing it myself I doubt the distro could do anything. how should I enable `a.out`

Comment: @technosaurus - while that is *possible* just because it is called a.out doesn't mean it is not elf - for some reason, the default output filename didn't seem to change with the default binary format.

Comment: What `config.log` says ? (configure suggested you to have a look inside it). Is your file system mounted readonly (have a look at `fstab`)?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès no it is not mounted readonly and also I pasted both config.log at the end. look at them again.

Comment: Sorry I missed the links...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mixed root/standard user builds at different steps? Look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173714/cabal-error-cannot-run-c-compiled-programs

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès No all of the steps have been done by the root (admin) (god) user of linux.

Comment: It possible you just need to add spaces before/after your additional cflags in case a make file has them butted up against another variable.  If not see if -march=generic works in case you're cpu is misidentified

Comment: If you try to build on say linux and try to write a.out to an external drive, this can cause the issues you are experiencing. I would build the code on your local linux drive then copy it to the external media, of some process similar to this.